# how to read/write bit by bit from/to memory in Java

Tags: java

The question is reached from the question: find all the prime numbers < 10^9. 
I used the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" to solve it, and I tried to use one bit to present the status of every number. So, following is my code

```
// n is the input integer
byte[] allNum = new byte[n/8 + 1];
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ((allNum[i/8]>>(i%8) & 0x1) == 0) {
        result.add(i);
        for (int j = 2; i*j < n; j++) {
            allNum[i*j/8] |= 1 << i*j%8; 
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

Is there a better data structure for this purpose? Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried BigIntege. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Hi Adi. Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that and it works. But, it seems shift a big number of bits (like 1M) will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`BitSet`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

```
BitSet composites = new BitSet(n + 1);
for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) 
  if (!composites.get(i)) {
    ... /* It's prime. */
    for (int multiple = 2*i; multiple > 0 && multiple <= n; multiple+=i) 
      composites.set(multiple); /* Strike out every i-th number. */
  }
```